# Firewall in Azure/AWS/IBM Virtual Machine ?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Web Application, Web Service and SQL-Server in Azure.

I'm trying now to duplicate those services to AWS and IBM as well, to figure out which of these vendors are best to suit me.

But I have a question that relate to all cloud vendors:

Do I need to configure a firewall in any of the VM that I'm using ?

I know that in azure I can choose "End Points" (IP & ports) to expose but this is the only protection I need ? I don't need to configure or install anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. These are very common requests. Cloud providers, such as azure, aws, ibm (By the way, I didn't really use IBM's) have the firewall setting ready, and this is one of big reasons to go to Cloud. You needn't deep knowledge on how to manage the firewall setting as in physical networking.

In AWS, as @Ron and @E.J. Brennan mentioned already, Creating security groups is the way to manage the firewall and it is easy, plus ***don't forget to setup public and private VPCs***.

I strongly recommend to read the relative documents first before you start to work on it. Here is the start:

[Amazon EC2 Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Answer (score 1):

Realistically speaking the VM firewall ( Endpoints in Azure and Security Group in AWS ) is sufficient. You may turnoff the ip-tables or windows firewall to have the control setting done at single place.

With that said there is no hard and fast rule to follow that, port - protocol - source combination based control is really effective.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about IBM, but AWS is much like Azure in that your 'firewall' is/can be managed at a higher level, not in the machine itself. In Azure they are 'end points' as you know, in AWS you do it with **security groups**.

By and large, if you are using the **security groups** correctly, there is no need to also use the firewall except in very rare cases, for specific purposes.